# Unable to locate the element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am coding in Java using Selenium Webdriver. I am unable to find the LINK Text "License Manager" in the page. When I tried switching to frame called `"text"`. Selenium was unable to locate the frame named "text" please help.

This is my code:

```
d.switchTo().frame("enterpriseStatus");
d.findElement(By.id("bannerSettingsButton")).click();//settings button
d.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
d.switchTo().window("name=text");//This is where something goes wrong
d.findElement(By.linkText("License Manager")).click();
```

This is the frame source:

```
<body>
   <div class="tablecontentarea-div" style="width: 90%;">
      <table class="tabletitlebar">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <span class="titlepage">Settings</span>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="tablecontentpanel" style="padding-top: 15px;">
         <table style="width:100%" summary="">
            <tr>
               <td style="width:50%; padding-right:7px; vertical-align: top;">
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/servers_32x32.png"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">Device Management</div>
                           <div>
                              Add, manage, configure and delete devices.
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/GettingStarted.do?actionName=main">Getting Started</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/DeviceListServlet">All Devices</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ArrayAssignment.do?actionName=listAssignments">Manage Agent Assignments</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-center">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/PolicyServlet?state=listPolicies">Policies</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/DeviceGroupList.do?actionName=showMainPage">Device Groups</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/FilersAssignment.do?actionName=viewNetAppFilerAssignment&filerAgentTypeID=401">NetApp Operations Manager</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ClusterAssignment.do?actionName=listAssignments">Virtualization (Assign ESX Hosts)</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-right">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do?sectionName=Arrays">Server Setup: Arrays</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do?sectionName=Database">Server Setup: Databases</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/alerting_36x36.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">Rules &amp; Alerting</div>
                           <div>
                              Setup rules that can perform a variety of actions, including running scripts.
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/RulesList.do?actionName=listRules">All Rules</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/RulesList.do?actionName=listRules&ruleTypeId=3">Threshold Rules</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/RulesList.do?actionName=listRules&ruleTypeId=2">Windows Event Log Rules</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-center">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/RulesList.do?actionName=listRules&ruleTypeId=6">Asset Change Rules</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/RulesList.do?actionName=listRules&ruleTypeId=5">Scheduled Rules</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-right">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do?sectionName=Real Time">Server Setup: Real Time</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ScriptList.do?actionName=showMainPage">Scripts</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/file_36x36.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">Files</div>
                           <div>
                              Configure file analysis, file rules, assign shares to agents. 
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/RulesList.do?actionName=listRules&ruleTypeId=1">File Analysis Rules</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/RulesList.do?actionName=listRules&ruleTypeId=4">Directory Analysis Rules</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-center">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/FileTypeGroupsList.do?actionName=showMainPage">File Type Groups</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/NasSharesAssignment.do">Assign Remote Shares</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/LocalSharesAssignment.do">Assign Local Shares</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-right">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do?sectionName=File Analysis">Server Setup: File Analysis</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/VmSharesAssignment.do">Discover VM Targets</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/FARepServlet">File Repository</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/user_accounts_36x36.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">Users</div>
                           <div>
                              Add, edit, and remove user accounts.
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/UserList.do?actionName=showMainPage">Manage Users</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-center">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do?sectionName=User Authentication">Server Setup: User Authentication</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-right">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
               <td style="width:50%; padding-left:8px; vertical-align: top;">
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/server_profiler_36x36.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">Storage Manager Server</div>
                           <div>
                              Configure and view information about your server.
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do">Server Setup: All</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/AboutDisplay.do?actionName=displayLicense">About</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-center">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do?sectionName=E-mail">Server Setup: E-mail</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-right">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/DataRetentionPolicies.do">Data Retention</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/web_update_36x36.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">Updates &amp; Upgrades</div>
                           <div>
                              Upload new modules and upgrade your agents and pollers.
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ModuleList.do?actionName=showMainPage">Upload Modules</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-center">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ModulePush.do">Upgrade Agents</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-right">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/reports_36x36.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">GUI &amp; Reporter</div>
                           <div>
                              Configure GUI and Reporting behavior.
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do?sectionName=Reporter">Server Setup: Reporter</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-center">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/ServerSetup.do?sectionName=GUI">Server Setup: GUI</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="link-col-right">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/license_36x36.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">License Summary</div>
                           <div>
                              View your license type and number of storage modifiers.
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="/LicenseManager.do?actionName=showLicenseManager">License Manager</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="setting-section">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="img-col">
                           <img src="/images/Icon.Thwack.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="desc-col">
                           <div class="titlesubwhitebg">thwack Community</div>
                           <div>
                              Import shared application templates posted on thwack, a community site for Solarwinds users. thwack features helpful devices, tips and downloads from over 20,000 network engineers. 
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <hr />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="link-col-left">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top"><a href="http://thwack.com/forums/63/profiler/185/storage/" target="_blank">Storage thwack Forum</a></td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: in html where is iframe code?

Comment: <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top">&#187;&nbsp;</td>
                                                        <td valign="top"><a href="/LicenseManager.do?actionName=showLicenseManager">License Manager</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>

Comment: Are you sure its under a frame? or a window? in your code u r switching to a window rather than a frame.... `d.switchTo().window("name=text");`. To switch to frame use `switchTo().frame`.

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code of the iframe element ?

Answer (score 1):

To switch to window you have to use WindowsHandle.

You may try using below function provided that you are handeling windows with different titles.

```
private String mainWindowsHandle; // Stores current window handle
 public static boolean swithToWindow(WebDriver driver,String title){
  mainWindowsHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
  Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // Gets all the available windows
  for(String handle : handles)
  {
    driver.switchTo().window(handle); // switching back to each window in loop
    if(driver.getTitle().equals(title)) // Compare title and if title matches stop loop and return true
     return true; // We switched to window, so stop the loop and come out of funcation with positive response
  }
  driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowsHandle); // Switch back to original window handle
  return false; // Return false as failed to find window with given title.
 }
```

Comment: Hey thank you all for your Help. I have used different "Settings" link in a frame named "text". That worked.